# Button Not working in 2 step modal

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello I have a problem with a form with 2 steps, where in the first step it will ask for address details and the second step it will take you to the visa details. The check out button in the second step  i cannot find out why it is not working.

The following is the code for the form:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="checkOutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="checkOutModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title text-primary" id="checkOutModalLabel">Shipping Address</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <form action="paymentPortal.php" method="post" id="paymentForm">
                <span class="bg-danger" id="payment_errors"></span>
                <div id="step1" style="display:block;">

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="firstName">Name: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="lastName">Surname: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="houseName">HouseName/No: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="houseName" name="houseName" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="street">Street: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="street" name="street" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="city">City: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="city" name="city" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="postCode">Post Code: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="postCode" name="postCode" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="country">Country: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="country" name="country" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="email">e-Mail: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="contactNo">Contact No: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="contactNo" name="contactNo" type="text">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div id="step2"style="display:none;">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="name">Name on Card: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="cardName" name="cardName" class="form-control"> <!-- NEVER enter name="" in credit card data handling because it may go to your server or you will be held liable -->
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="cardNumber">Card Number: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="cardNumber" name="cardNumber" class="form-control"> <!-- NEVER enter name="" in credit card data handling because it may go to your server or you will be held liable -->
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="cvc">CVC: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="cvc" name="cvc" class="form-control"> <!-- NEVER enter name="" in credit card data handling because it may go to your server or you will be held liable -->
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="expireMonth">Expire Month: </label>
                        <select id="expireMonth" name="expireMonth" class="form-control">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <?php for($i=1;$i <13;$i++) :?>
                                <option value="<?= $i ;?>"><?= $i; ?></option>
                            <?php endfor; ?>
                        </select> <!-- NEVER enter name="" in credit card data handling because it may go to your server or you will be held liable -->
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="expireYear">Expire Year: </label>
                        <select id="expireYear" name="expireYear" class="form-control"><!-- NEVER enter name="" in credit card data handling because it may go to your server or you will be held liable -->
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <?php $yr=date("Y");?>
                            <?php for($i=0;$i<11;$i++) : ?>
                                <option value="<?= $yr+$i ;?>"><?= $yr+$i ;?></option>
                            <?php endfor;?>
                        </select>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="check_address();" id="nextButton">Next >></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="back_address();" id="backButton" style="display:none;"> Back</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="checkOutButton"  style="display:none;">Check Out</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Moreover below is the jquery /ajax for the 2 step to work which I do not think it has anything to do with the error:

```
     function back_address(){
            jQuery('#payment_errors').html("");//clears errors if pass
            jQuery('#step1').css("display","block"); //hides modal with id="step1"
            jQuery('#step2').css("display","none"); //show modal with id="step2"
            jQuery('#nextButton').css("display","inline-block"); //hides next button 
            jQuery('#backButton').css("display","none"); //shows back button 
            jQuery('#checkOutButton').css("display","none"); //hides checkout button 
            jQuery('#checkOutModalLabel').html("Shipping Address"); //changes <h4> tags text to be displayed from Enter your credit card details!!! to Shipping Address
        }


        function check_address(){
            var data={
                'firstName' : jQuery('#firstName').val(),
                'lastName' : jQuery('#lastName').val(),
                'houseName' : jQuery('#houseName').val(),
                'street' : jQuery('#street').val(),
                'city' : jQuery('#city').val(),
                'postCode' : jQuery('#postCode').val(),
                'country' : jQuery('#country').val(),
                'email' : jQuery('#email').val(),
                'contactNo' : jQuery('#contactNo').val(),
            };
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : '/aresV2/admin/parsers/check_address.php',
                method: 'post',
                data : data,
                success : function(data){ //this data is what is forwarded back from the parser file
                    if(data != 'passed'){
                        jQuery ('#payment_errors').html(data);
                    }
                    if(data == 'passed'){
                        jQuery('#payment_errors').html("");//clears errors if pass
                        jQuery('#step1').css("display","none"); //hides modal with id="step1"
                        jQuery('#step2').css("display","block"); //show modal with id="step2"
                        jQuery('#nextButton').css("display","none"); //hides next button 
                        jQuery('#backButton').css("display","inline-block"); //shows back button 
                        jQuery('#checkOutButton').css("display","inline-block"); //hides checkout button 
                        jQuery('#checkOutModalLabel').html("Enter your credit card details!!!"); //changes <h4> tags text to be displayed from Shipping Address to Enter your credit card details!!!
                    }
                },
                error : function(){alert("An error occured!!!");},
            });
        }
```

In the development tools of the browser there is no errors in regards of the button, there is only warning which has to do with visa information handled on port 80.

It is the first time I am trying to this 2 step modal form/modal and any help with solving the issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well your submit button is outside of the `form` tag so if you are trying to have it submit the form to `paymentportal.php` it won't do that.  If there is another outer form then it will submit to that.

Comment: Awesome worked, thanks